# How to Add a "event Action<X,Y,Z>" to Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, interface, abstract

I have these two interfaces:

```
    public interface IEvent 
    {
        public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent;
        public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property);
    }

   public interface IEventListener
   {
       void Listen(EventInfo receiveInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property);
   }
```

I have these two Class too:

```
    public class EventManager : IEvent
    {
        public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent;
        public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property){};
    }


public class EventListener : IEventListener
{
    public virtual void Listen(EventInfo receiveInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property)
    {   
    }
}
```

And these other class too:

```
public class EventInstaller : MonoBehaviour 
{

    private Dictionary<IEvent,Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property>> eventSender;
 EntityEvent.Property>();

    private Dictionary<IEventListener, Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property>> eventListerner;
    

    public void AddSender(IEvent sender)
    {
        eventSender.Add(sender, sender.OnEvent);//-->error here
    }


    public void AddListener(IEventListener listener)
    {
        eventListerner.Add(listener, listener.Listen);
    }
```

and i want to do this:

```
public void Connect()
{       
    foreach (IEvent sender in eventSender.Keys)
    {
        foreach (IEventListener listener in eventListerner.Keys)
        {
            eventSender[sender] += eventListerner[listener];                 
        }
    }
}
```

The error says:

**The event 'OnEvent' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=**

How to fix this error?
thank you so much!!

//-------------------------------------------------

UPDATE

//-------------------------------------------------

I did this to resolve the problem:

```
  public interface IEvent 
    {
        public event Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent;
        public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property);
    
        public Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> GetEvent();
    
    }
    

        public class EventManager : IEvent
        {
    
            public Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> GetEvent()
            {
                return  OnEvent;
            }
    }
    
    
    
        
            public void AddSender(IEvent sender)
            {
                eventSender.Add(sender,sender.GetEvent()  );
            }
    
   

     if i do this i have the original reference or is a different instance?..
```

Comment: Events are like properties; they are an abstraction, not something you can store a reference to. That said, you question doesn't make any sense. You already have the `sender` object, so if you ever want the `OnEvent` event, you can just get it directly from the `sender` object. Your second error also doesn't make sense; as long as `Property` in the interface declaration is in fact `EntityEvent.Property`, `listener.Listen` is a perfectly good syntactical way to express a delegate that can be added as a value for that dictionary. There won't be any error where you say there is.

Comment: You are right ... the second error does not exist ... it was a mistake (copy and paste) when writing ... sorry ... I will correct it ...

I want the dictionary that way because I want to know the object that is the owner of the event in some moments. So I can filter and optimize the code better ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magic is removing the `event` keyword from `IEvent`. It prevents this delegation from calling from outside of `class`. Also, an `Interface` can contain only methods and properties. Convert fields to property.

```
public interface IEvent 
{
    public Action<EventInfo, EntityEvent.Type, EntityEvent.Property> OnEvent { get; set; };
    public void SendEvent(EventInfo sendInfo, EntityEvent.Type eventType, Property property);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help!! but it doesn't works... if you do that you get this other error (Interface cannot contain field)

Comment: Ok, thank you so much Mustafa!! I assume that is impossible to do what i want then :-(

Comment: Hi, I think i resolve the problem... if i do this i have the original reference or is a different instance?.... i going to put the code over there...